# Omni Completion with java

Tags: java, vim

I basically used to write C++ programs and I used OmniCppComplete with vim. It is working fine and I'm happy. Recently I started learning java, so I downloaded javacomplete from here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785. Now the problem is when I use "." to complete any classes or packages its not showing any pop-up. But when I'm using Cx Co, it's working. But OmniCppComplete is working as soon as I press "." on any classes or namespaces. What I'm missing in javacomplete? How will I make it work with "."? please help.

Comment: you should have a look at the eclim project

Comment: java... better go to an IDE. Personally I edit almost anything in vim, besides java... intellj's ideavim is fine, even though it cannot compare to real vim.

Answer (score 1):

Autocompletion is not a built-in feature. You need a plugin for that. Most autocompletion plugins are more or less language-agnostic while some language-specific plugins like OmniCppComplete give you autocompletion for free.

If you had read OmniCppComplete's doc you woluld know that the autocompletion feature you are used to is reserved to that plugin and you would already be looking (by yourself) for a generic autocompletion plugin because javacomplete doesn't do autocompletion.

Say... on vim.org.

Answer (score 1):

Completion plugins provide you *sources* (often classes, methods, and variable names from the current file). They still have to be triggered. Since most plugins use the *omni completion* extension point of Vim, that trigger is `<C-x><C-o>` in insert mode.

The OmniCppComplete plugin seems to add a custom completion trigger on the `.` (because that makes a lot of sense for C++). The Java pendant doesn't. If you would like to have a consistent behavior, either:

- add the `.` completion trigger for the Java completion yourself (taking implementation hints from the other plugin)
- submit an enhancement request to the plugin's authro
- switch to a generic completion plugin that handles multiple languages consistently